# How to use matplotlib with PyQt4

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I want to plot a figure with embedded matplotlib in PyQt.
I am using Qt Designer for the main window, and writing python code for the signal and slots connexion part.

So my code looks like this :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


qtCreatorFile = "main.ui" # my Qt Designer file 

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.figure = plt.figure()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.csvbutton.clicked.connect(self.plot)

    def plot(self):

        filePath="/path to csv file here"
        df= pd.read_csv(str(filePath),index_col='date')
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.hold(False)
        ax.plot(df, '*-')
        self.canvas.draw()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My main problem is the connexion between the Qt Designer file and the python code, I couldn't set a canvas widget directly in Qt Designer and I'm still struggling to find where the error lays in my code.
Your help is very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you didn't set the canvas in designer than, in its current state, your `self.canvas` is not included in any layout of the window. Try this: in designer make a container like object in the place you want to put the canvas (QWidget, Groupbox, etc.). In the code build your canvas, add it to a local layout (`QHBoxLayout` for example) and make a `.setLayout(canvaslayout)` in your container. This should place your canvas correctly in the UI.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use `matplotlib` in Qt Designer can not be done directly, for this we must promote a `QWidget` to use `FigureCanvas` or better a class that inherits from it as I show below, first we create a class called Canvas in file called canvas.py:

**canvas.py**

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.setParent(parent)
```

After creating the design through Qt Designer, we have all the elements we want, but where we want to place the argument we use the `Widget` element that is in `Containers`, and we name it `canvas`:

[image]

Then we promote it by right click and choose the option `promoted to ...`:

[image]

Obtaining what is shown in the following image, in `Promoted Class Name` we place `Canvas` as the name of the class, and in `Header File` we place `canvas.h` (in Header File the `file.py` file is placed, for example `package.subpackage.file.h`), then press `Add` and after `Promote`:

[image]

At the end we get a file structure similar to the following:

```
.
├── canvas.py
└── main.ui
```

Then we create the file main.py where we place your code with small variations:

**main.py**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


qtCreatorFile = "main.ui" # my Qt Designer file 

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.csvbutton.clicked.connect(self.plot)

    def plot(self):

        filePath="data.csv"
        df= pd.read_csv(str(filePath),index_col='date')
        ax = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.hold(False)
        ax.plot(df, '*-')
        self.canvas.draw()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the end we get the following:

[image]

You can find the complete project [here](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/8ec6ebca98f97306d9068014d658b5c5)

---

If you want to add the NavigationToolbar you can use the following code:

```
...
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar 

...

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))
        ...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's exactly what I needed to know.