# PyQt5: using loadUi with promoted widgets from Qt Designer

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, qt-designer, uic

Complete newbie to Qt and Qt Designer.
I tried following some tutorials online to figure a way to embed matplotlib graph in Qt.
Apparently the approach is to use subclass of QWidget which is done by "promoting" the QWidget.

I tried the approach shown in this SE [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369725/how-to-use-matplotlib-with-pyqt4) and this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C5VnE9wPhk)

Without promoting the QWidget, the *.ui file can be loaded into python without having any issue with the below script.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

But when I promote the QWidget as below, I get the following error.

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user.user\Desktop\pyqt_gui.py", line 11, in <module>
    window = Ui()
  File "C:\Users\user.user\Desktop\pyqt_gui.py", line 7, in __init__
    uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
...
...
...
  File "C:\Users\user.user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\qobjectcreator.py", line 115, in search
    module = __import__(mname, {}, {}, (cls,))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'canvas'
```

Could someone please shed some light on this ?

Comment: Where is the `Canvas` class? And the "canvas.py" file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the guides you followed don't explain clearly enough how to link the promoted widget to your `Canvas` class, since your screenshot shows the wrong values. When you first enter the *Promoted class name* in the Promoted Widgets dialog, Qt Designer will automatically fill in the *Header file*, so it will end up looking like this:

[image: screenshpt]

But this is intended to work with C++ projects rather than Python ones, so you need to change "canvas.h" to the import path of the Python module that contains your `Canvas` class. Thus, if that module is called "canvas.py" and is in the same folder as your "pyqt_gui.py" file, you would simply need to edit the *Header file* to "camvas" (i.e. without the extension). To fix your existing ui-file, you can re-open the Promoted Widgets dialog and then double-click the current header-file value to edit it (and then also *make sure you save the changes afterwards*):

[image: screenshot]

This will result in the following line being added to the generated Python module:

```
from canvas import Canvas
```

(If you want to preview this in Qt Designer, you can select Form -> View Python Code in the menu-bar).

---

NB: you can enter *any* valid Python import path as the *Header file*. So if your custom widget module was in a sub-package called "widgets", you could enter "widgets.canvas" instead. In addition, it's also possible to use relative imports by specifying the base-package via an argument to `loadUi`. In that scenario, you would enter ".canvas" (note the leading dot) as the *Header file*, and then call `loadUi` like this:

```
uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self, package='widgets')
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but this didnt work. I added a path to the Header file field and saved the canvas file. and used sys.path.append('C:/Users/.../Desktop') so that python can import it.

when compiled my ui file look like below

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

from C:\Users\...\Desktop\canvas import Canvas

Comment: @m2as3registeredservicesohmone As I stated very clearly in my answer, you only need to enter "canvas" (i.e. exactly as is shown in the second screenshot). This will result in the line `from canvas import Canvas` being added to the generated module. Also, you ***do not*** need to modify `sys.path` in any way. Please read my answer more carefully and make sure you follow the advice given there. (And note that the section at the bottom below the line is *optional additional information*, so you can ignore that for the moment).

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro, Tried it again and it worked as you stated. Thanks heaps.