# PyQt5 qobjectcreator not able to find module for promotion after being compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5

After compiling my code with pyinstaller, I seem to no longer be able to reference my promoted widget, as the `qobjectcreator` module lost track of where the header of the promoted widget is, presumably because pyinstaller moves the dependencies a bit and the code structure became messed up. Here is what my file structure looks like (before compilation):

```
application
├── app.py
├── folder1
│   ├── promotedWidget.py
│   └── dialog.py
├── uifolder
│   ├── app.ui
│   └── dialog.ui
└── app.spec
```

Note, the ui that contained the widget promotion is `dialog.ui`, and it made a reference to `promotedWidget.py` with the header `folder1/promotedWidget` in Qt Designer. This worked when I run `app.py` normally, the dialog opened with no issues but when I tried to run it after compilation the following error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 61, in createNewModel
  File "folder1\dialog.py", line 25, in __init__
  File "PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
  File "PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 66, in loadUi
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1037, in parse
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 828, in createUserInterface
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 806, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 503, in createLayout
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 806, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 503, in createLayout
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 806, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 546, in handleItem
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 806, in traverseWidgetTree
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 264, in createWidget
  File "PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 228, in setupObject
  File "PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py", line 100, in createQObject
  File "PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py", line 125, in findQObjectType
  File "PyQt5\uic\Loader\qobjectcreator.py", line 113, in search
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1\promotedWidget'
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue before, and if yes what was your solution?

Comment: try to add empty `__init__.py` to folder1 and uifolder

Comment: Had the exact same issue. Here's an answer that worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433557/19954013